# How to get multiple RecordSets from StoredProcedure with NReco.Data in Asp.NetCore

Tags: stored-procedures, datatable, asp.net-core, nreco

I use NReco.Data in my Asp.NetCore Application to make db-calls, because I don't want to use EF and DataTable isn't supported yet.

Now I need to call a StoredProcedure and get Multiple RecordSets (or Dictionarylists).

At the moment I called this:
`dbAdapter.Select($"STOREDNAME @{nameof(SQLPARAMETER)}", SQLPARAMETER).ToRecordSet()`

But the stored gives me more than 1 recordset, can anyone help me to get the others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently `NReco.Data.DbDataAdapter` has no API for processing multiple result sets returned by single `IDbCommand`.

You can compose `IDbCommand` by yourself, execute data reader and read multiple result sets in the following way:

```
IDbCommand spCmd;  // lets assume that this is DB command for 'STOREDNAME'
RecordSet rs1 = null;
RecordSet rs2 = null;
spCmd.Connection.Open();
try {
    using (var rdr = spCmd.ExecuteReader()) {
        rs1 = RecordSet.FromReader(rdr);
        if (rdr.NextResult())
            rs2 = RecordSet.FromReader(rdr);
    }
} finally {
    spCmd.Connection.Close();
}
```

As NReco.Data author I think that support for multiple result sets may be easily added to `DbDataAdapter` API (I've just created an [issue for that](https://github.com/nreco/data/issues/35) on github).

**-- UPDATE --**

Starting from NReco.Data v.1.0.2 it is possible to handle multiple result sets in the following way:

```
(var companies, var contacts) = DbAdapter.Select("exec STOREDNAME").ExecuteReader( 
  (rdr) => {
    var companiesRes = new DataReaderResult(rdr).ToList<CompanyModel>();
    rdr.NextResult();
    var contactsRes = new DataReaderResult(rdr).ToList<ContactModel>();
    return (companiesRes, contactsRes);
  });
```

In the same manner `DataReaderResult` can map results to dictionaries or `RecordSet` if needed.